# ActiveRecord DATETIME column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to `ActiveRecord` and trying to do something fairly simple. I searched the internet and was unable to come up with a solution.

In mysql I have a table column with a type of `DATETIME`. This table has many values in it already. Some example values for this column are `NULL`, `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, and `2009-04-30 10:30:22`

Using `rails` and `ActiveRecord` I can retrieve records from the database. However, when I ask for the value of a `DATETIME` field with the value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` the result I get is a `nil` object.

A database value of `NULL` also returns a `nil` object, which makes sense.

A database value of `2009-04-30 10:30:22` returns `Thu, 30 Apr 2009 10:30:22 UTC +00:00` which also makes sense.

I thought using `_before_type_cast` might help, but it does not.

How can I determine if the object returned has a database value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is no way built in to Rails to get around casting that date to something non-nil.

The fact that there is no way around this is a sign that you're probably doing something in a non-optimal way, so my first suggestion is to just migrate all `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values to `nil` if you can.

If that isn't an option. You can find out whether any one record has `0000-00-00 00:00:00` via sql conditions something like this:

```
Post.where("date_field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && id = ?", post.id).exists?
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree this may be non-optimal. However, I am working with a legacy PHP application and the `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values have significant meaning vs `NULL` values. I am surprised that there is not a better rails solution to this. You do get an up vote from me though. Thanks!